# Jupyter(Windows) not recognizing SPARK_HOME

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I have already set my SPARK_ENV variable in Windows to the following path:C:\Users\xxx\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6. When I run the below commands in Jupyter:

```
import
findspark.init()
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-a4bc4c9af84d> in <module>()
----> 1 findspark.init()

C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\findspark.py in init(spark_home, python_path, edit_rc, edit_profile)
    119 
    120     if not spark_home:
--> 121         spark_home = find()
    122 
    123     if not python_path:

C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\findspark.py in find()
     30 
     31     if not spark_home:
---> 32         raise ValueError("Couldn't find Spark, make sure SPARK_HOME env is set"
     33                          " or Spark is in an expected location (e.g. from homebrew installation).")
     34 

ValueError: Couldn't find Spark, make sure SPARK_HOME env is set or Spark is in an expected location (e.g. from homebrew installation).
```

I am not sure what else to do to rectify this problem. I am using these instructions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try `SET` on the command line to list all the environment variables? The problem is, `findspark` is unable to find Spark in the default locations, and probably `SPARK_HOME` is not set properly.

Please try to set `SPARK_HOME=C:\Users\xxx\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\libexec`, furthermore, the `SPARK_ENV` location is not required.

Comment: I tried setting SPARK_HOME to the path you mentioned and I still get the same error

Comment: Any other ideas as to why this I am having this issue?

Comment: Did you try to print an overview of all the environment variables. That would be the first step of debugging.